# How to return hidden SSID using NEHotspotHelper?

Tags: swift3, ios10

I'm using NEHotspotHelper to return the list hotspots around the user phone using below code but hidden SSID not return is the list there is any way to handle this issue

```
 var options:Dictionary<String, NSObject> = Dictionary(minimumCapacity: 1)
    options[kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName] = "subtitle" as NSObject?
    NEHotspotHelper.register(options: options, queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        (cmd) in
        if cmd.commandType == .evaluate || cmd.commandType == .filterScanList
        {
            if cmd.networkList != nil {
                for network: NEHotspotNetwork in cmd.networkList!
                {
                    //only visible SSIDs return
                }

            }
        }

    }
```